# Sharepoint 2010 (left and right Zones) - Remove

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

All I am trying to do is to remove the right zone of this site. How do I accomplish this?
Is there any site in SharePoint that doesn't have zones?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Web Part Zones are part of the Page Layout that your page instance is using. To remove a Web Part Zone you can:

- Edit the page in SharePoint Designer. Before placing the page into edit mode, SharePoint Designer will ask if you want to detach from the Page Layout. Once you do, you can now format the page however you would like.
- Create a custom Page Layout based on the out of the box Page Layout with the right zone removed. After your custom Page Layout is deployed or uploaded, you can associate your page with that layout.
- Hide the zone with custom CSS. The easiest way to do this is to add a Content Editor Web Part onto your page with the CSS to hide the zone.

Comment: I really like your options. I know very little about CSS, do you have a resource where I can take a look. Or, if you don't mind could you please provide a little code to put into the content editor! I have done this to hide the left menu, but don't know how to do it for the zones.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, I can't tell what Page Layout you are using, so I wouldn't what to guess. I would suggest using a tool like Firebug that would either tell you the element class or give you enough XPath information to specify the location. Then set "display: none".

Answer (score 3):

On the content Editor just insert the following and it works:

```
<script>

function HideWebPartZone()
{
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD")
  var i=0;
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    if (x[i].width=="70%")
    {
      // left column
      x[i].style.width="100%"; 

      // center (otherwise empty) column
      var x2=x[i].nextSibling;
      x2.style.width="0";
      x2.style.display="none";
      x2.innerHTML=""; 

      // right column
      x2=x[i].nextSibling.nextSibling;
      x2.style.width="0";
      x2.style.display="none";
      x2.innerHTML=""; 

      // right margin column
      x2=x[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      x2.style.width="0";
      x2.style.display="none";
      x2.innerHTML="";
      //all done
      return;
    }
  }
}


_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideWebPartZone")

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have edit access on the page, you should be able to set the Text Layout to one column to remove that right column.  This option is in the Editing Tools->Format Text->Text Layout section of the ribbon when in page editing mode.

Comment: I have tried clicking every place but I don't seem to get to the Editting tools. The only thing that comes close is the "Edit Properties" but once again Can't get it enabled. I have created the site using the system account, so I know it is not a permission problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I like Rich's idea of editing the page in Sharepoint Designer if the editing tools option doesn't show up in the ribbon. The editing tools section is probably tied to the page layout, which could explain why it doesn't show in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

once you are in sharepoint designer..please also try right clicking on the aspx file and select "Edit in Advanced Mode" - This will let you delete zones, columns and when you go to save the file you will get prompted to create a custom layout..say Yes...all done in one shot.